# wp_schedule_event every day at specific time wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, cron

I write Following code to run my function every day at 16:20 ..

But I guess is the problem in code..

not working

Epoch timestamp:  1427488800

3/28/2015 1:10:00 AM

```
if( !wp_next_scheduled( 'import_into_db' ) ) {
wp_schedule_event( time('1427488800'), 'daily', 'import_into_db' );

function import_into_db(){

////My code

}
add_action('wp', 'import_into_db');
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Old question but if someone looks for the answer, here it is:

Use strtotime() and pass hours.

In his case:

```
wp_schedule_event( strtotime('16:20:00'), 'daily', 'import_into_db' );
```

Answer (score 0):

`wp_schedule_event` first argument is the epoch you wish the schedule to execute for the first time, it's not Feb 28 yet.

Check that you're using the function correctly: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_schedule_event

Answer (score 0):

WP Cron runs, when somebody visits your website.
Thus if nobody visits, the cron never runs.

Now there are 2 solutions:

1. Disable WP Cron, use a real cron job and customize it.

https://support.hostgator.com/articles/specialized-help/technical/wordpress/how-to-replace-wordpress-cron-with-a-real-cron-job

2. Use a custom interval in `wp_schedule_event()`:

   ```
   function myprefix_custom_cron_schedule( $schedules ) {
       $schedules['every_six_hours'] = array(
           'interval' => 21600, // Every 6 hours
           'display'  => __( 'Every 6 hours' ),
       );
       return $schedules;
   }
   add_filter( 'cron_schedules', 'myprefix_custom_cron_schedule' );

   //Schedule an action if it's not already scheduled
   if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'myprefix_cron_hook' ) ) {
       wp_schedule_event( time(), 'every_six_hours', 'myprefix_cron_hook' );
   }

   ///Hook into that action that'll fire every six hours
    add_action( 'myprefix_cron_hook', 'myprefix_cron_function' );

   //create your function, that runs on cron
   function myprefix_cron_function() {
       //your function...
   }
   ```

and you can see these tuts

http://www.nextscripts.com/tutorials/wp-cron-scheduling-tasks-in-wordpress/

http://www.iceablethemes.com/optimize-wordpress-replace-wp_cron-real-cron-job/

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/10/16/schedule-events-using-wordpress-cron/

custom Wp cron

http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/cron_schedules

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/10/16/schedule-events-using-wordpress-cron/

http://www.viper007bond.com/2011/12/14/how-to-create-custom-wordpress-cron-intervals/

http://www.sitepoint.com/mastering-wordpress-cron/

https://tommcfarlin.com/wordpress-cron-jobs/

http://www.paulund.co.uk/create-cron-jobs-in-wordpress

cron linux

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-add-jobs-to-cron-under-linux-or-unix-oses/

http://www.thesitewizard.com/general/set-cron-job.shtml

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/scheduling-tasks-with-cron-jobs--net-8800

[google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=wp%20cron%20job%20wih%20real%20cron%20job&oq=wp%20cron%20job%20wih%20real%20cron%20job&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i64.21049j0j1&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#safe=active&q=wp%20cron%20job%20with%20real%20cron%20job&spell=1)